# SSH Public Key Management for a small team

Tags: ssh, security, ssh-keys, public-key

I'm setting up a deep-learning workstation in my college's lab. It's running Ubuntu Server 16.04 and I set up a SSH server in it, to control it remotely.

My task now is to make it available for my team to use it, via SSH using public key authentication (already disabled password auth). But I'm a little bit lost in some aspects about SSH public key management.

How do I manage pub-keys from the users that will be able to access the server?

What's the safest way to receive and store these keys inside the server?

Should they send me the pub-keys generated via ssh-keygen through message and store it myself on the server, or there is some more secure way to do that?

The team is around 6 people, so I think that managing the keys manually is viable in the case. Am I wrong?

Sorry about these bunch of questions, but I've been searching the web for the past two weeks about this topic and couldn't find anything useful for this case. Advice from your experience with server administration would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ssh-copy-id](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) might be of help to you, but that requires users to add their keys themselves, and in order to do that they need to be able to login (via passwords since ssh-keys aren't setup yet). The otherway to do this is to have them send you their **public** keys and then you add it to each of their authorized keys file. It is safe as long as they don't send their private keys. It's not the best long term solution but for 6 people it wouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is one thing that I think is an ideal use case for configuration management tools like Ansible/Puppet/Chef/etc.

Have people generate their keys, and store them as part of the data deployed by your configuration management system.

Comment: P.S. Ansible is a really easy system to get started with, and doesn't require a lot of infrastructure so might be a good option to start playing with.